# How to debug DynamicObject exception at application startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Checking the Common Language Runtime Exception while debugging, a series of three exceptions is raised.

The message (for all) says:

> Property path is not valid. 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject+MetaDynamic'
>   does not have a public property named 'Items'.

I've tried to find an `Items` property without success, but the fact is that I've never used a `DynamicObject` and I'm not able to find out where an intervention is needed.

Any other information in the exception stack is totally not understandable for human developers.

I'm pretty sure the only "Dynamic" in my code is the `DynamicResource` in my XAML and maybe that's the starting point.

**Update:**

This is one of the Styles where I set DynamicResource as Value of a property and an example  of usage.

```
<Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlueViolet"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And then used as a simple Button style:

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}"  Width="24" Height="24" Click="ShutDown" IsEnabled="False" />
```

**Update 2:**

The output message says of one of those apparently equal exception:

> Cannot get 'Name' value (type 'Object') from 'SelectedObject' (type
>   'Configurator'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedObject.Name;
>   DataItem='PropertyGrid' (Name='PropertyGridTab'); target element is
>   'PropertyGrid' (Name='PropertyGridTab'); target property is
>   'SelectedObjectName' (type 'String')
>   InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Property
>   path is not valid. 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject+MetaDynamic' does not
>   have a public property named 'Items'.

**Update 3:**

I've found one of the exception is related to Xceed Property Grid `SelectedObject` bound to custom View Model. It works perfectly but it raises the above "warning". I think this is a question for the Xceed Issue Team.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail, perhaps the XAML of said `DynamicResource`

Comment: I've used it in several places to load Styles, check the Edit for one of the examples (the others are totally equal).

Comment: This may not be related to the "Items" error, but is the definition for the button style and the usage in the same XAML file?

Comment: @Xtr no, they are in different files (I've used DynamicResource for this reason).

Comment: Just to confirm: 

If you don't set the style on the button, does it still give you the exceptions?

And if you disable the exceptions thrown (Debug - Exceptions - Untick all "Thrown") does it compile and run?

Comment: @Xtr yes, it works. If I change the SelectedObject (please, see the update #3) setting the properties list manually in the XAML it doesn't raise the exception. If I untick "Common Language Runtime Exception" it runs without any exitation

Comment: Yes, then the "Items" property would also be on the Xceed grid. It will probably be a first chance exception issue, which means that an exception was thrown but handled internally, by enabling your exceptions from the debug menu it will catch them regardless.